# Ошибка рендера страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Верстаю сайт и в какой-то момент появился баг, что часть одного блока сайта перестает рендерится (пропадает часть блока). Баг замечен только в **Chrome**, на 2х устройствах (больше нету) и с выключенными разширениями
Чаще всего происходит при переключении между окнами приложений или вкладками. ПК при этом не испытывает нагрузок (судя по диспетчеру задач). Авто обновления чего-либо на сайте нет, ошибок js/css: 0. Блоки снова рендерятся после наведения на них курсором или скролла.

На скринах ниже показано нормальный вид (1) и баг (2). При чем состояние с (1) на (2) меняется даже если ничего не делать, в рандомный момент, но не всегда одинаково и не выделяет какой-либо блок html элемента.

===========================================

UPD: после нескольких дней активного дебага было выяснено, что рендер 'ломается' от большого количества псевдоэлементов *::before* и *::after* (61 before 'ломает' блок). Те блоки, из которых они были удалены прекратили заливаться фоновым цветом, что несомненно путь к успеху.
И все равно я не понимаю почему это происходит

[image: бро]

[image: не бро]

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Что при этом говорит консоль? HTML уже сформирован? Стили есть? А другой браузер как себя ведет?

Comment: @SwaD проблема наблюдается  только в Chrome, при чем на 2 устройствах Windows
HTML сформирован полностью. После окончательной загрузки страницы может пройти хоть час, но баг все равно покажет себя, пусть даже я не буду переключаться на другое приложение

Comment: `Памагите!!!` -- Вы дебага по скриншотам ожидаете?